# How to override "Cannot asign must be an instance" in Django?

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Notification(models.Model):
    notification_author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notifauthor")
    notification_from = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notiffrom")
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)

def create_user_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Notification.objects.create(
                                    notification_author=instance.username,
                                    notification_from=instance.room)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def save_user_notification(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.username.save()
```

I am trying to create signal for creating notification after message is created. But have error:

Cannot assign "20": "Notification.notification_author" must be a "Profile" instance.

How to override it (if possible) without changing CharField to FK in Message model?

Found smth about eval(), but it does not still work

Comment: Changing your CharFields to ForeignKeys is the proper solution, correcting your models will make everything much simpler

Comment: I do understand, but separate Frontend starts not to work well and give the same error, so I wonder if there were a simpler way to override it

Comment: Notification Author - should be an object from Profile Model. You give a String. It can not work. I can imagine notification_author=Profile.objects.get_or_create(username=instance.username) . This can work

Comment: The question is how to convert the string to Profile model without using FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is how to convert the string to Profile model without
> using FK

```
notification_author=Profile.objects.get_or_create(username=instance.username)
```